# jQuery not executed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building an ajax upload with an editing function (rotate, zoom and crop), and I'm using guillotine by matiasgagliano (https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) for this. My problem is that after upload the user get redirected to the editing page through ajax, but when landing on that page I always have to refresh the page in browser for the image to load.

I've tried auto-reloading, both through js and php, but that doesn't help, neither does adding a button to load the same url again. Only refresh from browser button (tested in several browsers) works. I've tried implementing jquery.turbolinks, but that stopped guillotine functions from working.

I'm loading the guillotine.js in head section after jQuery, and have the function in bottom before body tag.

Any tip or help would be appreciated. Thx

Here is some of the code:
HTML:

```
<div class='frame'>
    <img id="id_picture" src="identifications/<?php echo $id_url; ?>" alt="id" />
</div>

<div id='controls'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='rotate_left'  title='<?php echo $word_row[434]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-rotate-left'></i></a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='zoom_out'     title='<?php echo $word_row[436]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-search-minus'></i></a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='fit'          title='<?php echo $word_row[438]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-arrows-alt'></i></a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='zoom_in'      title='<?php echo $word_row[437]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-search-plus'></i></a>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='rotate_right' title='<?php echo $word_row[435]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-rotate-right'></i></a>
</div>
```

Js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  jQuery(function() {
    var picture = $('#id_picture');

    picture.guillotine({
      width: 240,
      height: 180
    });

    picture.on('load', function(){
      // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
      picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});

      // Display inital data
      var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
      for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }

      // Bind button actions
      $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
      $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
      $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
      $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
      $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
      $('#process').click(function(){ 

          $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "scripts/process_id.php?id=<?php echo $emp_id; ?>&user=<?php echo $user; ?>", 
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                window.location = "<?php echo $finish_url; ?>";
            } 
          });

      });

      // Update data on change
      picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
        data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
        for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
      });


    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Open browser console.

Comment: You try wrapping your JS code with `$(document).ready();` ?

Comment: @ZanderRootman `$();` is the shortcode version of `$(document) .ready();`.

Comment: Did you try loading your page through Firebug in FF? http://getfirebug.com it is an essential tool if you really want to be serious about js development.

Comment: Script tags added via html insertion don't run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both the DOM-tree and the script is loaded.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "guillotine-master/js/jquery.guillotine.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () { 

jQuery(function() { 
        var picture = $('#sample_picture');

        picture.guillotine({
          width: 240,
          height: 300
        });

        picture.on('load', function(){
          // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
          picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});

          // Display inital data
          var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
          for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }

          // Bind button actions
          $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
          $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
          $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
          $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
          $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
          $('#process').click(function(){ 

              $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "scripts/process_img.php?id=<?php echo $emp_id;?>&user=<?php echo $user; ?>", 
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    window.location = "<?php echo $finish_url; ?>";
                } 
              });

          });

          // Update data on change
          picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
            data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
            for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
          });


        });

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly loading *Guillotine* **twice**, before and inside the *onload* handler.

You should initialize *Guillotine* after the image is loaded and just once:

```
var picture = $('#sample_picture');

picture.on('load', function(){
  picture.guillotine({
    width: 400, 
    height: 300,
    eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'
  });

  ...
});
```

If after fixing this you still get any troubles, be aware that if an image is already loaded the *onload* event never gets triggered, even if the image is not present but **cached** it might load before you set the handler for *onload*.

It's not that jQuery doesn't execute on page load but possibly that the *onload* event never gets triggered.

To prevent this you can force the image to be loaded, place this after setting the *onload* handler:

```
// Force reloading if completed or if undetermined.
if (picture[0].complete !== false) {
  // 1x1 gif
  gif = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=='
  // Save original src, replace with the gif and reload the original src
  src = pic.src; pic.src = gif; pic.src = src
}
```

I hope this solves your problem, don't lose your faith in Guillotine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the respond guys, but i was unable to solve it.
As soon as I wrapped any function around the jQuery function, the functions within it stopped working.
I ended up using Jcrop instead of Guillotine, and built a rotating function that can be used before cropping. Now everything is working well.

Link to Jcrop: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html